# How to remove element from java.util.List?

Tags: java, collections

Everytime i use .remove() method on java.util.List i get error UnsupportedOperationException. It makes me crazy. Casting to ArrayList not helps. How to do that ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {

    private List<Image> images;

    public void removeImage(int index) {
         if(images != null) {
            images.remove(index);
         }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:144)
model.entities.Product.removeImage(Product.java:218)
    ...
```

I see that i need to use more exact class than List interface, but everywehere in ORM examples List is used...

Comment: which List implementation are you using, the stack trace should make this obvious.

Comment: It looks like you're using some ORM.  You may want to consult its docs to determine the correct way to do this.

Comment: sure your list has entrys? remove() should be the right way to go. please post your complete stacktrace, maybe there's some more information in it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all lists allow you to remove elements. From the documentation of `List.remove(int index)`:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list **(optional operation)**.

There is not much you can do about it, except creating a new list with the same elements as the original list, and remove the elements from this new list. Like this:

```
public void removeImage(int index) {
     if(images != null) {
        try {
            images.remove(index);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException uoe) {
            images = new ArrayList<Image>(images);
            images.remove(index);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: nice answer (+1), but I'd challenge the word "Unfortunately". I think it's a feature that some lists are immutable.

Comment: @Seanizer, hehe, I agree with you! For the OP it's still unfortunate I suppose ;)

Comment: @aioobe:But the List is an interface... that means we are to implement all the methods if we are implementing this interface for a concrete class... In that case, how can that be optional: "not all lists allow you to remove elements"... 

so in that case it throws 'UnsupportedOperationException' deliberately?

Comment: Exactly. `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` is a valid implementation of `List.remove` according to documentation.

Comment: The only "improvement" I would make is to make the method return an Image, so that the contract would be similar to `List` (return the removed item or null if not found).

Comment: The signature of the method was given in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Its simply means that the underlying `List` implementation is not supporting remove operation.

NOTE: `List` doesn't have to be a `ArrayList`. It can be any implementation and sometimes custom.

Answer (score 2):

Casting your list to array list won't change a thing, the object itself stays a List and therefore you only can use the List properties

what you should try is to create it with new ArrayList